# jQuery each() and "on success"?

Tags: jquery

I'm using `$().each()` to loop through some items. I want to make sure that the action that follows after this piece of script is only executed when `each()` has completed.

Example:

```
$('something').each(function() {
  // do stuff to items
});

// do something to one of these items
$('item').etc
```

It seems to work at this point, because it's a really basic action. But sometimes it fails and it seems like the `each()` part is still busy, causing the action of the follow-up script to be overwritten by the `each()` actions.

So... is this possible? Or is code below the each() function always executed *after* the previous code. I know that e.g. AJAX calls have a "success" function, to force code to only execute when the parent action is completed. Is this needed/possible here? I tried something like the following, but this doesn't seem to be working:

```
$('something').each(function() {
  // do stuff to items
}, function () {
  // do stuff when the each() part has completed
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`each` isn't asynchronous, so whatever comes after *should* execute afterwards and there isn't any support for a callback. However, it will  depend what your 'do stuff to items' does, because some of this could be asynchronous - eg animations, slide up/down, etc - and these methods support callbacks.